# how to develop web app to sell online

Tags: php, e-commerce, banking

I have made a booking system for online ticket reservations, but they cant pay online! so I now I have a client that he wants me to make them able to pay tickets online.

The problem is that I have never worked with ecommerce before. Is there any good book or tutorial how to start with developing for banks? because my client is going to choose the bank that will give me the gateway to make the transactions.

What is the first thing to do? are there any instructions from the bank, how to setup the gateway? or they will help me? or I must know all this by myself? what are your recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using a hosted payment solution whereby the bank providing your clients merchant account has an API that presents a payment page to the user (as opposed to collecting card details your self which you should **not** do [large, enforceable regulatory requirements - PCI DSS]) then they will provide all the API documentation you need.

If your using an off the shelf shopping cart module, if your lucky there may be existing plugins for that banks API.

Comment: They said to me that they have contract with "Danske Bank" they allow them to sell online.

Comment: @ToolCooL: If they say so, let them give you the Specs and Policies then you know what you can work with.

Comment: Then I would contact them and ask for details of their ecommerce API/offerings for existing merchants

Comment: @Alex K. Thank you for your advice I had the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a payment gateway such as Paypal, WorldPay, SecPay etc... these companies often have API's or messaging protocols you can use.

This would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to pay for your solutions, but you can pay via premium SMS too, there are companies who provide world-wide connectivity such as txtNation, Zong, etc.

Like the other couple have mentioned there are WorldPay, PayPal, MB, etc.

If you want to broaden your horizons though, look into premium SMS payment systems.

You can integrate these solutions using their pre-made solutions or you can go straight through their gateways using their API's.

Comment: I am gonna look into that too thnx

Comment: No problem at all, the way I figure it is that the more options you have (without being daunting) the better. Also ~everyone has a mobile phone which they can make payments through so yeah, it's defiantly something to think about.